# Инструменты разработки под веб

Tags: фреймворк, веб-программирование

Как могут сосуществовать одновременно проприетарные и свободные фреймворки - asp.net, zend, djang, rails и тд ? Почему все не приходят к выбору бесплатного инструмента в бесплатной операционной системе ? Или может, деньги теряют вес в этом вопросе ? Помогите разобраться, а то судя по описанию все веб-фреймворки схожи.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В платный фреймворк включена техподдержка от компании.

Если у тебя приложение должно работать 24x7 и каждый час простоя приносит большие убытки(не только деньги, но и репутация, клиенты) при возникновении непредвиденных ситуаций, то выбор проприетарного ПО может быть лучше и являться более оптимальным вариантом. Если ты берешь свободное ПО, то справляться со всем придется самому, а ситуации бывают разные и порой нахождение решения не тривиальное(проблемы смены сервера, расширения приложения, добавления функционала, апгрейда до новой версии, исправление багов и ошибок и т.д. и т.п.).

Answer (score 1):

Когда у заказчика есть деньги, он хочет получить максимум производительности, безопасности, надежности и масштабируемости. Если его выбор падает на ASP.NET, то это только случайность, что ASP.NET проприетарен, так как не он один отвечает всем этим требованиям. Другой вопрос в том, почему крупные компании часто используют открытые технологии (Facebook, VK - PHP, Google - Python). Тут ответ прост - их авторитет не позволяет им использовать технологии конкурирующих компаний, а своего нет или есть, но не взлетело, в виду отсутствия интереса у программистов.